# Find all documents taking to long on pymongo

Tags: mongodb, performance, pymongo

I have a collection of ~12,000 documents which doesn't fit in memory, so I read it in chunks with the following code:

```
    pipeline = [
    { "$project": {"_id":0, "leagues":1, "matches":1, "nick":1, "ranked_stats":1,"sum_id":1 } },
    { "$skip": skip },
    { "$limit": limit }
]
query = db['summoners'].aggregate(pipeline)
```

It takes 90 seconds to run each of these chunks for 1,000 document on Pymongo, even though on Robomongo (or mongodb shell) it takes around 0.1 seconds. Am I missing something here?

EDIT: I already tried using .find() along with .limit(), the time spent is pretty much the same as using .aggregate(), which is around ~0,09 seconds/document

Comment: Skip and Limit in any form is not an effective way to "page" data, You should be selecting by "range" instead and using `.find({ _id: { $gt: lastSeenId }).limit(limit)` instead. You also should not be using `.aggregate()` when there is no reason to and `.find()` will simply do the job.

Comment: I tried it like this, but it yields me MemoryError in python, cause the find runs before limiting the number of rows fetched.

Comment: Because you are trying to fetch too many documents in one request. Please don't make statements like "I tried this" on this site without actually including in "great detail" exactly what you are actually doing. No-one has the time to chat back and forth. You need to include enough information in your question so someone can look at that, see what you are actually doing, and then correct you with a better process. Best to get to improving the content in your question.

Comment: I just mentioned I had already done what you suggested. I didn't explicit it on the question's content cause I thought I was doing the wrong thing. And even using a small pool the time spent on find() is pretty much the same as using aggregate(), which is arount ~0,09 seconds/document